# Why does my PC suddenly no longer work with SSD drives, but works fine with HDD drives?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, bsod, sata

I've had my main desktop PC for years, running Windows on a 250GB Samsung Evo SSD. A couple of months ago, all of a sudden I get lots of bluescreens at completely random moments. Mostly IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL, but the fault message varied.

I've analysed minidumps, ran Memtest86+, ran chkdsk, everything, to no avail. I switched out the SSD for an old HDD I had lying around, installed Windows, and it runs absolutely fine, with no BSODs whatsoever. I ordered a new SSD, installed it, installed Windows... and the BSODs were back. I've switched SATA cables and SATA ports, installed windows with the drives running in AHCI mode and in IDE mode... nothing works. I've switched out the PSU, thinking the HDD may be more robust in weird voltage fluctuations or something, but to no avail. As long as it is an SSD - random crashes. If I use an HDD, everything is fine. The weirdest thing is that I've run this exact same system with that exact same SSD drive without any problems for years.

My next step would be ordering a new mainboard and switching that out, guessing that it might be a problem with the SATA controller, but who knows? Anyone who can make an educated guess at what could be the culprit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mmmhhh... Weird....

This could be a case of borderline flaky memory. Even though Memtest86 is fine with it. I have seen that before.
As a result the RAM can't always keep up with fast/bulk data-trasnfer from/to the SSD. 
RAM timing (in the RAM itself or the motherboard) can degrade slightly over time, especially on a system that is over 5-6 years old.

If your Bios has the "spectrum randomisation" option (or something to that effect) switch it off.
If you can clock your RAM at slightly lower speed try that too.
If you have multiple DDR strips test with only 1 strip in there. If the DDR's have different timing/brands swap them in the slots (may cause the Bios to select a different timing pattern, which may have more stability).
If that improves stability you found the problem.

Regardless what causes your problem I would recommend to replace the motherboard and RAM anyway. Spontaneous BSOD's will sooner or later cause data loss and Murphy's Law dictates that will happen at the worst possible moment, causing maximum damage.

Given that you state this is an elderly system in that case upgrading to a brand new and faster modern system is probably more value for money than trying to fix the old system.

Comment: I took out a DIMM and everything runs like a charm now, even on SD. I guess you 're right about the fast data transfer problems. Weird. What's even more spectacular is how well Windows 10 still runs on only a single 2GB DDR2 DIMM! Anyway, thanks for the suggestion!